# Почему неправильно отображается шрифт Museo Sands в IE11?

Tags: css

Подскажите, почему в IE 11 не отображаются некоторые шрифты?

Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Например такой шрифт

```
@font-face{ font-family: 'Museo Sans Regular'; src:url('../font/MuseoSans.ttf'); }
```

Comment: название шрифта? какой формат шрифта?

Comment: @font-face{
     
    font-family: 'Museo Sans Regular';
    src:url('../font/MuseoSans.ttf');
}

Comment: используйте формат woff - https://caniuse.com/#search=woff + woff2 - https://caniuse.com/#search=woff2

Answer (score 0):

переконвертируйте свой ttf шрифт. Не знаю можно ли давать ссылку, но есть онлайн сервисы для этого. Просто в гугль забейте "конвертер шрифтов онлайн"

форматы и броузеры:

eot - IE6+

woff - IE9+ / FF 3.6+ / Opera 11+ / Chrome 6+ / Safari 5.1+ /Opera mobile 11+

ttf и otf - FF 3.5+ / Opera 10+ / Chrome 4+ / Safari 3.2+ / Opera mobile 10+ / iOS 4.2+ / Android 2.2+

SVG- Opera 9+ / Chrome 4+ / Safari 3.2+ / Opera mobile 10+ / iOS / Android 3

Таким образом как вы могли заметить разные броузеры и их версии поддерживаю разные форматы шрифтов. Уменя в каждой верстке присутствуют все!!!